# How to set Included Columns via a Liquibase change set when creating an MSSQL Index

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

I need to write a Liquibase changeset for creating an index that has both Key Columns and Included Columns.

While Key Columns I can set (Liquibase supports this) I don't know how to set Included Columns.

By Included columns I refer to this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx

Comment: How to use included column in liquibase

Comment: This question should be re-opened as it might be useful for documentation purposes around support for MSSQL index properties via Liquibase. Question was updated to reflect the actual problem, knowing if native Liquibase supports Included Columns (it doesn't via a native changeset attribute, as confirmed by the accepted answer; workaround however exists, using SQL type changeset with plain SQL).

Answer (score 4):

Use `<sql>...</sql>` tags (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html) to execute any database-specific query using Liquibase. There is no support for this attribute in Liquibase XML dsl: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/create_index.html.